# Converting from string to int in file from the internet

Tags: python, string

My program is supposed to download a file from the internet and then to guess at a persons salary based on certain factors such as age, work, etc. It seems to me that it is not letting me turn the string into an int which I need to do. As I'm still new to python, any help would be appreciated. The main error occurs here:

```
below_count = 0

for row in myfile:

    if ages_midpoint > int(row[0]):
        count_below50+=1
```

The error is:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Comment: `row[0]` is not an integer character. Perhaps the line was empty, perhaps there was just a space. And are you sure you want to look at *just* the first character of each line?

Comment: sorry ill post the entire code, row is a dictionary in it

Comment: The problem isn't with your conversion, it's the fact that there's no data in `row[0]`.

Comment: What do you expect row to be?

Answer (score 2):

The error message tells you exactly what is wrong.

1. If you're looping over a text file with `for`..`in`, that means the value `row` is a string (one line from the file).
2. You are looking at `row[0]` which is the first character of the string.
3. That character is a space (I assume, because calling `[0]` on the empty string would throw an exception), which is not a legal representation of a decimal number.

You need to go back to what you're actually trying to do and re-think how to do it, because this isn't it.

Answer (score 0):

The value of row[0] is an empty string. You can recreate the error by doing the following on the command line interpreter...

```
>>> int('')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

You might want to validate the value stored in row. `if row:` will do it.

Unfortunately there's not enough information in your post to be able to help you much beyond that. the line of code `if ages_midpoint > int(row[0]):` is very suspicious. Is row a line of text from a text file, if so row[0] will return the first character... probably not what you want. Use the string split function `word = row.split(<charToSplitOn>)[0]`

Answer (score 0):

This might help.

```
>>> int('3')
3
>>> int('')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

so, you can strip off any whitespace and put a `try..catch`.

```
below_count = 0

    for row in myfile:
        try:
            if ages_midpoint > int(row.strip()[0]):
                count_below50+=1
        except ValueError:
            # row[0] is not an integer character
            # do something here
            pass
```